# Copy files using Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, mist

I want to create a Smart Contract which can copy a file from one location in a computer to another location in the same computer.

I am new to Ethereum and don't know how to proceed. Any help with the code will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Akil, Can you explain little detail, I didn't get your point

Comment: explain this problem detail .Do you want to create a private network and you want to communicate on another computer?

Comment: I have already created a private Ethereum blockchain. I have also installed Mist. Now I want to develop a smart contract to copy files from one folder to other.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create a Smart Contract which can copy a file from one location in a computer to another location in the same computer.

Smart contracts run as bytecode inside the EVM being run by the client. The EVM is a virtual machine which doesn't have access to the local disk of the host. Also note that the contract would be run on all machines in the network. They may or may not have the same files on disk, which would lead to potentially different behaviour on different nodes.